# Read csv and jump to a specific index

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm facing a problem while reading a csv file. I'd like to read a csv file line for line and then jump to a specific line (e.g 3). This is my code so far

```
    with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    #check if field 12 ist empty
    for row in reader:
        if not row[12]:
            #Add the orders
            orders.append(row)
```

Now I'd like to jump in orders to the index 3 (here some i-index). This is my "thinking".

```
for i, row in enumerate(orders):
#print the i index with the value which is stored in cell 12
#this isn't working...
    print(orders[i][12])
```

Thanks for any ideas/help!

Comment: `itertools.islice` is your friend

Comment: @dawg so could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file.csv
Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarren House,312,3.75
Belinda Jameson,2017,Cushing House,148,3.52
Jeff Smith,2018,Prescott House,17-D,3.20
Sandy Allen,2019,Oliver House,108,3.48
```

You can use [islice](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the specific line you wish:

```
import csv 
import itertools as it 

with open('/tmp/file.csv') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    print(next(it.islice(reader, 2,3)))
# ['Jeff Smith', '2018', 'Prescott House', '17-D', '3.20']
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-)